# In Azure Search - can I specify WhitespaceAnalyzer from the .NET SDK?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I basically have the same need as this fellow:
[Azure Search Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303438/azure-search-analyzer/34304353#34304353)

I want to store a series of space-delimited tags in "tags", each of which may contain limited punctuation chars. Is formulating a POST to the REST API the only way to go?

I suppose I could encode the strings as a last resort.

```
        var definition = new Index()
        {
            Name = indexname,
            Fields = new[]
            {
                new Field("id", DataType.String)                            { IsKey = true },
                new Field("objectType", DataType.String)                    { IsSearchable = false, IsFilterable = true, IsRetrievable = true },
                new Field("referenceId", DataType.Int32)                    { IsSearchable = false, IsFilterable = false, IsRetrievable = true },
                new Field("name", DataType.String)                          { IsSearchable = false, IsFilterable = false, IsRetrievable = true },
                new Field("tags", DataType.Collection(DataType.String))     { IsSearchable = true, IsFilterable = false, IsSortable = false, IsFacetable = true, IsRetrievable = true },
            },
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom analyzers are not yet supported by the SDK, and using the REST API is the only way to use them for now. We'll add support for customer analyzers to the SDK when this feature is out of preview (and possibly earlier).