# Azure Search highlights each search term included as part of phrase search

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

I have noticed that when performing a phrase search with double quotes, azure Search return appropriate search results but it highlights each individual word in the phrase.
For example when we do phrase search on “data scientist” it highlights “Data”  and "Scientist" as well ideally it should have highlighted just “data scientist”.

Is this the default behavior of Azure Search and is there any way to alter it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the default behavior of Azure Search and is there any way to alter it.

Unfortunately there is no way to customize this behavior at the moment.
In Azure Search we use Lucene's Postings Highlighter. This highlighter ignores positions of terms that matched, that's why you see all phrase terms highlighted independently.

You could refer to the similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411353/azure-search-highlights-for-phrases-with-double-quotes).

If you want to promote this feature to achieve you could go to [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) page and vote for it.