# How do I search within a word within a searchable field? "Contains" search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a search index with 4 custom analyzers. Two of them are for language specific searching, and the other 2 are for "exact" searching (no need for lemmatization). For simplicity, I am including only the info for the language specific custom analyzers, although the overall solution will need to be applicable to all the custom analyzers.

```
{
    "tokenizers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MicrosoftLanguageStemmingTokenizer",
            "name": "text_language_search_custom_analyzer_ms_tokenizer",
            "maxTokenLength": 300,
            "isSearchTokenizer": false,
            "language": "french"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MicrosoftLanguageStemmingTokenizer",
            "name": "text_language_search_endsWith_custom_analyzer_ms_tokenizer",
            "maxTokenLength": 300,
            "isSearchTokenizer": false,
            "language": "french"
        }
    ],
    "analyzers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
            "name": "text_language_search_custom_analyzer",
            "tokenizer": "text_language_search_custom_analyzer_ms_tokenizer",
            "tokenFilters": [
                "lowercase",
                "lang_text_synonym_token_filter",
                "asciifolding"
            ],
            "charFilters": [
                "html_strip"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
            "name": "text_language_search_endsWith_custom_analyzer",
            "tokenizer": "text_language_search_endsWith_custom_analyzer_ms_tokenizer",
            "tokenFilters": [
                "lowercase",
                "lang_text_endsWith_synonym_token_filter",
                "asciifolding",
                "reverse"
            ],
            "charFilters": [
                "html_strip"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For simplicity, lets assume the index has only 2 searchable fields.
 - CategoryLangSearch (uses text_language_search_custom_analyzer)
 - CategoryLangSearchEndsWith (uses text_language_search_endsWith_custom_analyzer)

Now assume the index has only 1 document, with the following:
 - CategoryLangSearch field value of "TELECOMMUNICATIONS"
 - CategoryLangSearchEndsWith field value of "TELECOMMUNICATIONS"

Our UI/API layer has logic so if the user searches TELE*, it will now to use CategoryLangSearch as the field to search in. Likewise, our UI/API layer will detect if the user searches with an asterisk wildcard in the front. So if the user searches for *TIONS, the UI/API layer is smart enough to instead search against the CategoryLangSearchEndsWith field.

All that is great... it works exactly as intended.

The problem, however, is what can we do if the user searches with * COMMU *
(ignore the spaces... S.O. treats the asterisks as signal for bold. The user types in asteriskCOMMUasterisk where asterisk is *)

I thought it would be "smart" if I built the azure search param like this: (CategoryLangSearch:(COMMU*) OR CategoryLangSearchEndsWith:(*UMMOC)) but, in practice, I found that this does not find TELECOMMUNICATIONS ORGANIZATION. This makes perfect sense when I see the query we build.

SO, my question is, how do we pull this off? Can we pull it off in Azure Search in anyway, shape or form? I don't see a path to success for this one. The only possible solution I could see is the following:
 1. If user searches for *something*...
 2. first query our MS SQL server directly to search using %something% syntax which is supported in SQL.
 3. find the IDs the match, and then use THAT to search against Azure Search index.

Comment: Hey Andres, side note, since the two tokenizers you define have the exact same configuration, it's enough that you define one and use it in both of your customer analyzers. This will keep you index definition cleaner but has no impact on service performance of behavior.

Comment: Thank you @Yahnoosh... didn't even notice that one but it makes sense :) I'm all about making things simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can issue 'contains' search in Azure Search.

1. First approach is using regex expression in the Lucene query syntax. In your example, if you issue a regex query /.*COMMU.*/, the search query will first expand to all terms in the search index that contain the string 'commu' then find the result. You can issue the regex query against the field for "exact" matches. The search query would look like : 
   docs?search=exact_field:/.*COMMU.*/&queryType=full.
2. The approach above is recommended if you have a small index because the query expansion process to find queried pattern is costly, especially for broad searches like /.*a.*/.  You can preload the work by using a ngram tokenfilter at *indexing time*. The configuration for the tokenfilter will be as below.

> ```
> {
>   "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NGramTokenFilterV2",
>   "name": "ngram_tokenfilter",
>   "minGram": 1,
>   "maxGram": 100
> }
> ```

Given a text "hello" for example, this tokenfilter generates ngram tokens as

> h, e, l, l, o, he, el, ll, lo, hel, ell, ..., hello.

When querying against the new field analyzed with ngram tokenfilter, you do not need wildcard or regex operator, but can use a regular term search. The search query "docs?search=ell" will find the document containing the term "hello". This approach avoids the expensive expansion process because all the "contains" possibilities have been preprocessed, and exist in the index. Please note that you need the ngram analysis at indexing time only.

Please also note that this ngram analysis impact the size of the index as it produces more tokens. You can use parameters 'minGram' and 'maxGram' to control the size of the index.

Since you already have an API/UI that directs the search based on the positions of '*', the second option seems like a good approach.

Nate

Comment: Thank you for the response @Nate-Ko. I'm not sure if I have done this correctly. I tried to apply this NGramTokenFilterV2, but it vastly increased our indexing time and the results were quite disastrous. I did my usual test of simply searching for femme and the search index considered pretty much every single document a match. Our highlighting also went completely bonkers, highlighting almost every word in each document. Am I supposed to have another set of searchable fields with this NGramTokenFilterV2 and search against those? Or do I need separate custom analyzers, 1 for indexing with...

Comment: ... NGramTokenFilterV2 and another custom analyzer for searching that doesn't have the NGramTokenFilterV2?

Comment: Thank you Nate. This NGram token filter was the key to solve this issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Nate!
But it isn´t completely correct.

If you use the "ngram_tokenfilter" like this it will generate exactly six tokens:
*{ h, he, hel, hell, hello }*.
You could create a second "ngram_tokenfilter" and set the "side" parameter to "back" to get the desired behaviour.

I had a pretty similar problem, maybe it can help: [Azure-search: How to get documents which exectly contain search term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253298/azure-search-how-to-get-documents-which-exectly-contain-search-term)

Have a nice day guys!

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. The 'side' parameter applies to edgeNGramTokenFilter. The proposed solution uses NGramTokenFilter. Let me know if I missed something. :)

Comment: Oh yea you are right, i overlooked it ;) My solution uses the edgeNGramTokenFilter. Sry for that